# EntityFramework fail on update entity - cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

I'm having this known problem with my application.
I've tried a lot of changes with HasKey and HasAlternateKey, even HasIndex, Unique and other variations on the OnModelCreateCreating() method.
I even re-mapped my entity but still no success!

> The instance of entity type 'Imoveis' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the key value '{Cod: 91}' is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached.

My Update() method of my BaseRepository class:

```
    public T Update(T entity)
    {
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; <-- Exception happens here
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
```

How the Update() is called. This problem it's happening on both calls. The second try is a fail way to prevent this error:

```
public Imoveis InsertOrUpdateUniqueName(Imoveis imoveis)
{
    try
    {
        if (imoveis.Cod > 0)
            Update(imoveis);
        else
            Insert(imoveis);
        return imoveis;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (imoveis.Cod > 0)
        {
            if (ex is DbUpdateException)
            {
                if ((ex.InnerException as SqlException)?.Number == 2627)
                    return UpdateImovelDuplicado(imoveis);
            }
            else if (ex is InvalidOperationException)
            {
                var local = DbContext
                    .Set<Imoveis>()
                    .Local
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Cod.Equals(imoveis.Cod));
                if (local != null)
                    DbContext.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
                return Update(imoveis);
            }
        }

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that SQL is pretty irrelevant here. Can you please show how the `Update` is called and where `entity` comes from?

Comment: @GuruStron thanks! I've updated with the Update() call. I'm maintaining the SQL because someone else can use that.

Comment: How are you managing your DbContext lifecycle?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm using a single instance of DbContext created during the Dependency Injection setup and injecting it through ServiceCollection.AddDbContext()

Comment: You can't use a singleton. Take a [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)

Comment: @Crowcoder but I'm using AddDbContext() like advised by the lifetime doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core

Comment: @mayconfsbrito then you must be using the context in another scope without calling SaveChanges before you use it where you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Solutions:

1 - In MY CASE (a console app), I removed async inserts or updates because I use a singleton DbContext. But this is NOT mandatory and depends on the case. You need to understand the life cycle of your DbContext.

2 - I changed my Update() method to recover and detach the original object from the DbContext Set collection.

This is my new Update() method calling a new DetachLocal() method for generic objects.

```
public T Update(T entity)
{
    DetachLocal(entity);
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}

public void DetachLocal(T t)
{
    var keyname = GetIdName(t);
    var keyValue = GetIdValue(t);

    var local = DbContext.Set<T>()
        .Local
        .FirstOrDefault(entry => GetIdValue(entry).Equals(keyValue));
    DbContext.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
    DbContext.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Thanks to @Crowcoder and @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for the replies that put me in the way to find this solution.